# WebException при загрузке файла

Tags: c#, winforms, сервер, http-status-code-404

Скажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего возникает следующая ошибка

```
private string[] DownloadFileFromServer(string from, string to)// Функция #1
{
    // try
    // {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(from , to);
        }
        string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(to);
        File.Delete(to);
        return file;              
    // }
    // catch { MessageBox.Show("Отсутствует соединение с сервером. Программа закрывается"); Application.Exit(); return null; }
}
```

`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка HTTP 404, которую возвращает сервер, указывает, что ресурс, который вы запрашиваете, не найден.

Убедитесь, что в аргументе `from`, который передается в метод `DownloadFileFromServer` содержится адрес существующего ресурса. Для теста попробуйте скопировать этот адрес в браузер и загрузить файл с его помощью.

Comment: Программа работает стабильно первое время, ошибка возникает лишь через некоторое время в процессе работы, адреса файлов все правильные

Answer (score 1):

В исключении указан код ошибки сервера **404**.

В кратце это значит (цитата из Википедии):

> При связи по HTTP клиент требует ответа на свой запрос к серверу.
>   Например, веб-браузер запрашивает HTML-документ (веб-страницу) и
>   ожидает цифровой код ответа и, не всегда обязательно, сообщение. В
>   коде 404, первая цифра «4» указывает ошибку клиента, к примеру,
>   опечатку в URL. Следующие две цифры определяют конкретную ошибку. HTTP
>   использует трёхзначные коды, напоминающие коды для ранних версий
>   протоколов FTP и NNTP.
>
> Следом за кодом ответа 404 для человеческого понимания идёт объяснение
>   причины. Спецификация HTTP предлагает фразу «Not Found» (не
>   найдено) и большинство веб-серверов по умолчанию выводят страницы
>   HTML, который включает в себя как код 404, так и фразу «Not Found».
>
> Ошибка 404 часто возвращается, когда страница была перемещена или
>   удалена, или не совпадает имя файла в коде и на сервере. В первом
>   случае, лучше возвращать клиенту код 301 Moved Permanently, что можно
>   настроить в конфигурации большинства серверов, либо производить
>   перенаправление на другой URL. Во втором случае, лучше возвращать код
>   410 Gone. Однако, так как эти два варианта требуют специальной
>   настройки сервера, большинство веб-сайтов не используют их.
>
> Ошибку 404 не следует путать с ошибкой DNS, которая появляется, когда
>   данный URL ссылается на имя несуществующего сервера. Ошибка 404
>   означает, что сам сервер был найден, но не смог найти запрашиваемую
>   страницу.

Т.е. ошибка либо на Вашей стороне (неверная ссылка), либо на стороне сервера (за период с последнего запроса страница поменяла адрес).

Comment: Ссылки все верные

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, тогда дело в сервере. User-Agent установлен?, куки - разрешены? Не бывает чтобы сервер просто так футболил.

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, есть еще момент с загрузкой файлов. Должна быть прямая ссылка на файл! Так же есть всевозможные защиты от автоматического скачивания файлов, которые, например, требуют JavaScript и отдают прямую ссылку только после того, как функция JS выполнится.

Comment: User-agent'a нет

Comment: @ZOOMSMASH, пробуйте выставлять данные, смотрите какая ссылка. Тут только методом проб и ошибок выявлять причину.